# What is the default fontsize, fontname and shadow for titles in Navigation Bar?

Tags: iphone, uilabel, uisegmentedcontrol, uinavigationitem, titleview

I'm trying to have a button on the self.navigationItem.rightButton that toggles a segmented control that is placed in self.navgivationItem.titleView .. this will however remove the title that is first set by self.title when the navbar is created .. I dont know if my approach is bad but I figured I could rotate between a UILabel and the Segmented Control in the titleView.

It works as I would like it to, however I cant figure out what size and font and shadowoffset and shadowcolor the default titles in a navigation bar is .. could you help me with a solution that either not force me to override the navigationItem.titleView or help me figure out the information needed to make a UILabel look exactly like the default titles.

Thankful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In code, something along the lines of:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/11648-change-uisegmentedcontrol-font-size.html

should help, except you'll be querying the size, name etc. of the UILabel.